# jQueryUI : Menu selections within tabs serializable to URL?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, pushstate

Does anyone know of a jQueryUI mechanism which saves the current “state” of the UI into the url, and can reproduce that state from the url?

I have menus within tabs as below.  (using jQuery UI tabs).

```
<div class="tabsx"> 
 <ul> 
  <li><a href="#tab1">First Tab</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#tab2">Second Tab</a></li> 
 </ul> 
 <div class="tab" id="tab1">
    <select id=”s1a”><option …… </select>
    <select id=”s1b”><option …… </select>
 </div>
 <div class="tab" id="tab2">
  <select id=”s2a”><option …… </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

If I make selections within a tab, click to another tab, and come back to the prior tab, the selections have been preserved, of course.

But I want is to have each possible "state" of the displayed page be referable via the URL.  So I want the browser URL to be changed to something like:

Example.com/page/?s1a=foo&s2a=bar#tab1

when I am looking at Tab 1, with the first menu on option 'foo' and the second on option 'bar'.

And, if this URL was entered into the browser, I want jQuery to display that same display state.

I have gotten as far as adding a function to the “activate” events such that the URL is changed when each tab is clicked .

```
$( ".tabsx" ).tabs({
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
        tab_href= ui.newTab.find('a').attr('href');
        window.history.pushState(null,null,tab_href);
      }
    });
```

I added a similar handler to the “create” event so that on page load, the default tab’s hash is put into the url. (Replace "activate" with "create", and "newTab" with "tab")

This works fine in that a url, such as:

```
Example.com/page/#tab2
```

appears in the browser’s url field when the second tab is activated. It can be bookmarked and when called, jQuery will show the second tab opened (standard behaviour).

So far, so good. But now I want to store the state of the selects in the url too.

I started coding (parsing the query parameters, searching the options list, etc).

But I wonder if there is some obvious short-cut available.